# Creating a specific dataset with LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, group-by, sum, difference

I have trouble with creating one specific "dataset" from list of objects which I get via Dapper from database. So the thing is about daily attendancies in company, so user comes and click and goes out and click and we have one table row like this:
[sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5W19.png)
So I have a model class like this:

```
    public class Attendance
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeUtcIn { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeUtcOut { get; set; }
        public string DayOfTheWeek { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TotalTime { get; set; }
        public byte StatusId { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan BreakTime { get; set; }
    }
```

and then after a call to the database I have result like this `IEnumerable<Attendace>`:

```
var result = await _platformDB.Con.QueryAsync<Models.Attendance.Attendance>(query);
```

then I created a simple viewmodel like this:

```
    public class Time
    {
        public DateTime DateTimeUtcIn { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeUtcOut { get; set; }
    }

    public class AttendaceViewModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string DayOfTheWeek { get; set; }
        public List<Time> TimesInAndOut { get; set; }
        public string Locations { get; set; }
        public string TotalTime { get; set; } //need to calculate
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string BreakTime { get; set; } //need to calculate
     }
```

and here comes the QUESTION now: how can I create `List<AttendaceViewModel>` from my result grouped by UserId and calculate TotalTime for one day (sum of all dateTimeUtcIn + dateTimeUtcOut) and breaktime for this day and also populate this  `List<Time> TimesInAndOut` in here?
I have really no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i know what you need:

```
List<AttendaceViewModel> resultList = result
    .GroupBy(a => (a.UserId, a.FullName, DateIn: a.DateTimeUtcIn.Date, a.DayOfTheWeek, a.LocationId, a.StatusId))
    .Select(ag => new AttendaceViewModel
    {
        UserId = ag.Key.UserId,
        FullName = ag.Key.FullName,
        Date = ag.Key.DateIn.ToString(),
        DayOfTheWeek = ag.Key.DayOfTheWeek,
        Locations = ag.Key.LocationId.ToString(),
        Status = ag.Key.StatusId.ToString(),
        TotalTime = new TimeSpan(ag.Sum(a => (a.DateTimeUtcOut - a.DateTimeUtcIn).Ticks)).ToString(),
        TimesInAndOut = ag.Select(a => new Time { DateTimeUtcIn = a.DateTimeUtcIn, DateTimeUtcOut = a.DateTimeUtcOut }).ToList(),
        BreakTime = CalcBreaks(ag.Select(a => (a.DateTimeUtcIn, a.DateTimeUtcOut))).ToString()
    })
    .ToList();
```

For the `BreakTime` i used this helper method:

```
private static TimeSpan CalcBreaks(IEnumerable<(DateTime inTime, DateTime outTime)> times)
{
    if (!times.Skip(1).Any())
        return TimeSpan.Zero;

    TimeSpan totalBreakTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
    TimeSpan lastLeaveTime = times.First().outTime.TimeOfDay;

    foreach(var attendanceTime in times.OrderBy(at => at.inTime).ThenBy(at => at.outTime).Skip(1))
    {
        TimeSpan breakTime = attendanceTime.inTime.TimeOfDay - lastLeaveTime;
        totalBreakTime += breakTime;
        lastLeaveTime = attendanceTime.outTime.TimeOfDay;
    }

    return totalBreakTime;
}
```

Comment: can you msg me on Discord maybe: *D1No*#4850

Comment: Yeah you got my point! Thats it now only have tio calculate breaktime which is time between this records in TimesInAndOut.,

Comment: @D1No: look again

Comment: Yeah I missed it, thank you Tim, I think now I got the point! This is a solution for my problem! Cheers

Comment: There is only one problem more here, so when user comes to work and clicks in, there is only DateTimeUtcIn record but DateTimeOtcOut is not populated until user clicks for out, which means that total time is then some negative number and at the end it not calculating it correct then.

Comment: @D1No: isn't it easy to fix? Maybe create also a method like i did for the break-calculation, then this task becomes very easy. Replace this calculation: `a.DateTimeUtcOut - a.DateTimeUtcIn` with `a.DateTimeUtcOut == DateTime.MinValue ? TimeSpan.Zero : a.DateTimeUtcOut - a.DateTimeUtcIn`

Comment: Ok, yeah I think I got the point, thank you, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able accomplish that with just LINQ. You should be able to loop over the items returned in the results that you just fetched, and do your logic there.

Implement a function like this, and call it after retrieving your results. You could even handle the database querying in this function too if you'd like, then just call the function and get back your list.

```
private List<AttendanceViewModel> GetAttendanceViewModels((whatever type 'results' is goes here) {type} results)
{
    var output = new List<AttendanceViewModel>();
    foreach(result in results)
    {
        var totalTime = CalculateTotalTimeForOneDay(result);
        var breakTime = CalculateBreakTime(result);
        result.TotalTime = totalTime;
        result.BreakTime = breakTime;
    }
    return output.GroupBy(u => u.UserId)
}
```